# how i should solve this problem?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$\int \frac{\text{d}x}{(1+\sqrt{x})(x-x^2)}$

how i should solve this problem ? 
i think we should take $x=\sin^2(x)$ and then proceed but still not able to solve , please help !

Comment: I think that the easiest way is to substitute $x=t^2$ and then proceed by partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: "$x = \sin^2(x)$": Aaargh! Do you mean $y=\sin^2(x)$, or $x=\sin^2(y)$? (In other words, don't re-use variable names like this.)

Answer (score 3):

HINT:
Let $\sqrt x=y\implies x=y^2,dx=2y\ dy$

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{(1+\sqrt x)(x-x^2)}=\int\dfrac{2y}{(1+y)y^2(1-y^2)}dy$$

[Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html):
$$\dfrac1{(1+y)^2y(1-y)}=\dfrac A{1-y}+\dfrac By+\dfrac C{1+y}+\dfrac D{(1+y)^2}$$

Comment: Hi lab , great solution. Off Topic , but do you know of any good book or website with techniques for indefinite integration?

Answer (score 0):

Using the substitution $x=\sin^2t$ we have the following:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dx}{(1+\sqrt{x})(x-x^2)}&=\int\frac{2\sin t\cos t \,dt}{(1+\sin t)(\sin^2 t)(1-\sin^2 t)}\\
&=\int\frac{2\,dt}{(1+\sin t)\sin t\cos t}\\
&=\int\frac{2(1-\sin t)\,dt}{\sin t\cos^3 t}\\
&=2\int (\tan t)^{-1}\sec^4 t\,dt-2\int \sec^3 t\,dt\\
&=2\int (\tan t)^{-1}(\tan^2 t + 1 )\sec^2 t\,dt-\sec t\tan t-\ln|\sec t+\tan t|\\
&=\tan^2 t+2\ln|\tan t|-\sec t\tan t-\ln|\sec t+\tan t|+C\\
&=\frac{x}{1-x}+\ln \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1-x}-\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\right)+C\\
&=\ln\left[\frac{\sqrt{x}}{(1+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{1-x}}\right]-\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}+C
\end{align*}